# Parse the markup received after an ajax call?

Tags: jquery, html

I am doing an ajax call to a server side function that returns an html response made only of two DIVs, like for example

```
<div id="divOne">text on divOne</div>
<div id="divTwo">text on divTwo</div>
```

Can I parse the markup response to extract only the text part included in the DIVs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `success` callback, say it's `function(data) {}`, you can use the returned data as a [context](http://api.jquery.com/context/) to look in, for example:

```
success: function(data) {
  //if these elements are nested down in a response, in another element
  var combinedText = $("#divOne, #divTwo", data).text();
  //if your response contains *only* these elements
  var combinedText = $(data).text();
  //of again if it contains *only* these elements and you want to filter which
  var combinedText = $(data).filter("#divOne").text();
}
```

The format is just [`$("selector", context)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1), whatever your ideal selector is.

Or in the case that your response contains *only* what's in the question, and they're root level elements, you need to [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead...since [`$("selector", context)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) is a [`$(context).find("selector")`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) internally, it won't find any elements at the root level in the returned data.

---

Or if you're using [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) specifically, you can use a selector on the end to get that entire element, like this:

```
$("#something").load("myPage #elementToGet");
```

Comment: @Nick Craver: are you sure that this way it works? In my case inside a success callback if I use your suggestion the "combinedText" variable is empty whereas the data passed contains the markup that I wrote in the question...

Comment: @Lorenzo - Perhaps I misunderstood, if that's *all* it contains just `$(data).text();` works, since they're root level elements...or if there are others, then `$(data).filter("#divOne").text()` for example to just get the first `<div>`.

Comment: @Nick Craver: I used this way: `var title = $("#divOne", response).text(); var message = $("#divTwo", response).text();`.

Comment: @Lorenzo - I updated to make this a bit clearer, if your response contains *only* these elements and they're not inside anything, you'll need `$(response).filter("#divOne").text()` to get the element/text you're after.

Comment: @Nick Craver: Thank you! Also my question was not so clear... :)

Comment: @Lorenzo - Welcome!  I would update the question though, saying your response contains only that content...may help the next guy finding this :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regular expression that will strip out html tags and leave just the data you require:

```
 String noHTMLString = htmlString.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
```

You will get

```
inputString.split('\n')  # --> ['Line 1', 'Line 2', 'Line 3']
```

This is identical to the above, but the string module's functions are deprecated and should be avoided:

import string

```
string.split(inputString, '\n')  # --> ['Line 1', 'Line 2', 'Line 3']
```

Alternatively, if you want each line to include the break sequence (CR,LF,CRLF), use the **splitlines** method with a **True** argument:

```
inputString.splitlines(True)  # --> ['Line 1\n', 'Line 2\n', 'Line 3']
```

Hope this helps if you need any more help do let me know.

PK